# How to record how much data is deleted in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7

I have the following batch file

```
@echo off
Del *.tmp /s /Q
Del *.temp /s /Q
Del Thumbs.db /s /Q
pause
```

I need it to record how much data it has deleted in the following formats

How much in data (KB)

How many files it has deleted

Does any one know a code I could use?

Comment: I thought about this and did some testing. The only way to do it is by doing the `dir` prior to the delete like the 2 answers give but in my testing, there were files in use that could not be deleted, so it isn't 100% accurate.

Comment: Thanks I am going to do some testing so i can find out how accurate they are and i may need a diffrent solution if they are too inaccurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion

set filePattern=*.temp

set totalSize=0
for /F "tokens=* usebackq" %%a IN (`dir /b ^| findstr /R .!filePattern!$`) DO (
    set size=%%~za
    set /a totalSize=!totalSize! + !size!
)

del !filePattern! /s /Q

set /a totalSize=!totalSize! / 1024
echo Total size deleted (!filePattern!): !totalSize! KB
pause
```

You may have to change the `!filePattern!` accordingly based on your desired files to be deleted. Besides that, you may have to place this batch script on the same directory as the files to be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo info about deleted files:
@for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /-c /a-s *.tmp^| findstr /i "File(s) Directory"') do (
   @echo  %%a
)
@del *.tmp /s /Q
```